# how to get the count of inbuilt serial ports availability in vxworks

Tags: vxworks

Is there a way to know how many inbuilt serial ports are available?. We can enable or disable these ports, when the vxworks image is built. For example, if I give command `/devs` it lists `/tyCo/0` and `/tyCo/1`. I want to know is there a way to know that there are 2 inbuilt serial ports available.

Comment: You might find a clue in SIO_CHAN * sysSerialChanGet(int channel) of sysSerial.c

Comment: @JaeMannYeh The reason I asked is because I have an extra XMC serial card put into my board, so if I want to access any serial port of it(say `/tyC0/n`), I have to pass device number as (`n - no. of inbuilt serial ports`), while creating the device using `tyCoDevCreate` function. But right now I'm hardcoding `no. of inbuilt serial ports` as `2` in this operation